# Subtracting two recursive tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing an arbitrary precision calculator and I'm tying to write a function that subtracts two nested tuples.

Tuples are represented as:
For the number 12345, the tuple will look like `(1,(2,(3,(4,(5, ())))))`

This is my function. It uses a function that returns the tuple with the larger value and utility function to access members and find the length of the tuple.

```
def subtractLists(list1, list2):
    borrow = 0
    result = ()
    larger = findLargerValue(list1,list2)
    smaller = list2 if larger != list2 else list1
    index1 = len_rlist(larger)-1
    index2 = len_rlist(smaller)-1
    nonzero = 0
    while index1 >= 0 and index2 >= 0:
        item1 = getitem_rlist(larger, index1)
        item2 = getitem_rlist(smaller, index2)


        if index1 == nonzero:
            borrow = 0
            item1 -= 1
        if item1 >= item2:
            result = makeRlist(borrow + item1 - item2, result)
            index1 -= 1
            index2 -= 1
        else:
            newindex = index1-1
            while getitem_rlist(larger, newindex) == 0 and newindex >= 0:
                newindex -= 1
            nonzero = newindex
            result = makeRlist(10 + item1 - item2)
            borrow = 9
            index1 -= 1
            index2 -= 1

    return result
```

If I apply this function on lists that represent the numbers 12345 and 999 the output is:

```
12345-999 = (6,None)
```

Here's `makeRlist`:

```
def first(s):
    """Return the first member of the recursive list"""
    return s[0]
def rest(s):
    """Return the second member, which is the rest of the recursive list"""
    return s[1]
def makeRlist(first,rest=None):
    """Create a recursive list"""
    return (first,rest)
```

Comment: How is a negative number represented? The first digit-tuple is negative, like `(-6,None)`?

Comment: Furthermore can you provide the implementation of the `makeRlist` function?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The finished product is supposed to represent negatives too, but i couldn't use it on positive too, so I'm taking one step at a time.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem makeRlist added

Comment: "For the number 12345, the list will look like (1,(2,(3,(4,(5, ())))))" That is a nested tuple rather than a nested list. Do you mean `[` and `]` rather than `(` and `)`?

Comment: @JohnColeman I stand corrected, mad a mistake when writing the question. I meant a nested tuple.

Comment: Also -- if you have freedom for *how* you can represent integers, you picked one of the worst possible ways. With such nested lists it would be much easier to represent `12345` as `[5,[4, ...` rather than `[1,[2, ...`. Furthermore, what is the point of the nesting? Why not simply `[1,2,3,4,5]` or `[5,4,3,2,1]`?

Comment: @JohnColeman This is a part of a college project, and the instructions were to implement this in a procedural way. So, I wanted to implements a list as a class, and was told not to use classes since it isn't suppose to be OOP. I know that this is a terrible representation, but I must do it.
I'll change the list order to (5,(4...

Comment: Why not simple lists? If you weren't specifically told to use recursion and nested data structures, just use regular flat lists. You don't need to create any classes to use lists. With lists you can implement elementary school algorithms for basic arithmetic in a way which is both straightforward and procedural. If anything, you risk making your project more like Lisp -- which is considered a functional rather than a procedural language.

Comment: @JohnColeman The instructions were to use linked lists. And this is the closest thing that the instructors permitted us.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you needed ?

`toRecursiveList` transforms a number to a tuple in a tuple in a tuple...

`recursiveSubstract` recursively substract every number and eventually retains a unit when it encounters negative numbers.

`getDepth` returns the depth of the tuple (length of the number)

`substract` is the method you call to do the substraction using two numbers, it will fill the tinyest with zeros so the now numbers have the same size.

```
def toRecursiveList(n, i = 0):
  return (int(str(n)[i]), toRecursiveList(n, i + 1)) if i < len(str(n)) else ()

def recursiveSubstract(l1, l2):
  tuple, toRet = (), 0
  if l1 != () and l2 != ():
    sub = l1[0] - l2[0]
    if l1[0] - l2[0] < 0: sub, toRet = sub + 10, 1
    next, ret = recursiveSubstract(l1[1], l2[1])
    tuple = (sub - ret, next)
  return tuple, toRet

def getDepth(l, i = 1):
  return getDepth(l[1], i + 1) if l[1] != () else i

def substract(n1, n2):
  l1, l2 = toRecursiveList(max(n1, n2)), toRecursiveList(min(n1, n2))
  while getDepth(l1) > getDepth(l2): l2 = (0, l2)
  return recursiveSubstract(l1, l2)[0]

print(substract(12345, 999))
```